# Display: inline-block isn't working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

It's so frustrating when something as simple as this won't work.. I want the nav to be inline-block when the screen is 800px or smaller. Can anyone see where I have done something wrong?

I'm using @media screen and (max-width: 800px) too make sure when the CSS should change and that the nav should go from the left side with display:block, to be on the top with display:inline block (where the different links should be inline).

**Snippet**

```css
nav {
  clear: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  width: 18%;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid pink;
  }
  nav a {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="index.html">home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="contact.html">contavt</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: replace `nav a` with `nav li`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply

### display: inline-block

to

## nav li

rather than

### nav a

```css
nav
{
 clear: left;
 text-decoration: none;
 float: left;
 width: 18%;
}

nav ul
{
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-left: -40px;
}

nav a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid brown;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 90%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
{
 nav
 {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid pink;
 }

 nav li
 {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
 }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="index.html">home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="contact.html">contavt</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

float none here

```
 nav
 {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  float: none;
 }
```

Comment: I have tried float: none; but it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign the "inline-block" display attribute to the list items tags (li) instead of the anchor tags (a).

For an example of this, examine this [Listamantic](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal01.htm) page with your browser's "Inspect" feature to see the CSS attributes used to create inline list items.